# c3.js chart and wkhtmltopdf

Tags: pdf-generation, javascript, wkhtmltopdf, c3.js

I'm using c3.js (http://c3js.org/) and wkhtmltopdf (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to generate a PDF of the HTML page my chart lives on. My chart displays fine in the browser but is blank in wkhtmlpdf. Wkhtmltopdf reports no Javascript errors but the resulting PDF does not include the chart. Does anyone have a work around for this?

`/wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 5000 "http://c3js.org/samples/chart_donut.html" ~/test.pdf`

[image: test.pdf]

Comment: Did you already find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, I ended up implementing my charts using D3 instead of C3

Comment: @Royw, answer is now below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Upgrade to the latest version** or there are a few workarounds explained
here https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1964 which appear to have resolved this issue.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @KevinBrown there are many different work arounds listed there which may or may not be applicable depending on the specific version the user is using.